# Div value increment javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, delay, increment

I am trying to make a div with an animated value increasing up to it's final value. Here's an example from themeforest: http://demo.themesvision.com/drupal/evolve/ (Happy customer, projects completed, etc)

I've tried lots of different code lines with no success. I was able to do the increment, but can't figure how to make a delay each time there's an increment. I've tried setTimeout() and setInterval().

Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    test();

    function test(){
        var i = 0;
        while ( i <= 100 ) {
            $("#test").text(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
});
```

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;

    test();

    function test(){
        $("#test").text(i++);
        if(i < 100) {
            setTimeout(test, 500);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I guess i had the code all scrambled!

Comment: No worries! It can be a bit of a challenge to get your head round the first few times.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { //For loop easier than while loop
    setTimeout(function() { //SetTimeout
        document.getElementById('test').textContent++; //...Where you increment the textContent
    }, i * 20); //...At interval of 20ms
}
```

Comment: That won't work mate - you got to do a recursive loop. All those timeouts will be added at the same time

Comment: @megawac The timeouts expire at different times. Try running it yourself.

Comment: Oh true I gotcha not the way I would do it ;)

Comment: But there is no problem to stack xxx timeout like this (resources speaking) ?

Comment: @Biduleohm No, browsers should be able to handle thousands of timeouts like this without a sweat.

Comment: Hmmm. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should! The browser will cope, but it's a waste of resources.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now the curiosity push me to go see how timers are handled. @iain_simpson I strongly agree.